# How to let user login with either username or email, in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need to let users log in either with a username or email address.

here is the login route.

```
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  const user = await Users.findOne({
    where: {
      username: username,
    },
  });
```

so I am using sequelize is there a way to implement this functionality?

thanks

Comment: Since you want to have multiple condition, you can use `OR` .  `const user = await Users.findOne({
    where: { [Op.or]: [{username}, {email}],  {password}
    },
  });`

Comment: What kind of session store are you using? Where is the rest of your route? Are you using passport.js?

Comment: Nope I am not using a passport, just  token, and sequelize

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = await Users.findOne({
  where: {
    password: password,
    $or: [
      { username: {$eq: username },
      { email: {$eq: email }}
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answer, so in this case I need to change the client-side code as well right?

Comment: and without changing the client code I just tried and got this response.


Error: Invalid value {
  username: { '$eq': 'hello@gmail.com' },
  emailAddress: { '$eq': undefined }
}

Comment: The password should not be stored as plain text, but hashed, this is bad advice IMHO.  Also searches for a user with that password and email/username. The question was broadly "how to log in"

Comment: Hey, yeah i know this, and i didn't share that part, but the password has been hashed:_))))

thanks for advice>